# ClassCastException when starting E-Mail Intent

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, classcastexception

I'm trying to send an email using email intent. This is my code:

```
/** Called when the user clicks the send button */  
public void cont_sendEmail(View view) {
        final EditText nick = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contNick);
        final EditText feas = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contFeas);
        final EditText tip = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contTip);
        String totalNick = nick.getText().toString();
        String totalFeas = feas.getText().toString();
        String totalTip = tip.getText().toString();
        String totalText = totalNick.concat(totalFeas);


    // Do something in response to button
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("message/rfc822");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"sando@live.se"});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "New contribution!");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , totalText);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    try {
       startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
      Toast.makeText(ContributeActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

When I press the "send" button and activates cont_sendEmail, the app crashes. This is my logcat:

```
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3691)
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3686)
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649):    ... 11 more
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
08-17 14:29:16.445: E/AndroidRuntime(12649):    at com.sandtdevelopment.getrich.ContributeActivity.cont_sendEmail(ContributeActivity.java:18)
```

(How do I paste the logcat to be readable?)

What can be the problem?

Comment: The problem is right in your stack trace: ClassCastException. You're trying to cast a TextView to an EditText. That probably happens in one of your findViewById lines.

Comment: For logcat formatting, use the code format i.e. indent 4 spaces or use the `{}` button in editor.

Comment: Ha, well look at that. Didn't even look at the xml file. Changed the TextView to EditText and it works fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are having an error with the casting of your `EditText` instances at the top of your class. Did you accidentally define one of the three as a TextView in your XML? The ID that you are using to refer to it could perhaps also be wrong. If this is the case and you fix it, your error should go away.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I did, I defined one as a TextView instead of EditText. Problem solved, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
>   cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

You are obviously trying to cast a TextView to an EditText which cannot work.

I see two possible reasons for that error:

> - Sometimes whean your are doing heavy changes on your layout using the    Layout Creator the IDE can get a little confused and mix up
>     things. Please try **CLEANING your project**.
> - You are actually making the misstake of doing the wrong Cast. In this    case, **check your code and see if you are accidentially
>     casting a    TextView to an EditText** (it is possible that you simply **mixed up some View IDs**). It could for example be the case that one of your referenced IDs above is not an EditText. Please check "R.id.contNick", "R.id.contFeas" and "R.id.contTip".

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I found the problem, and it as me accidentially using TextView instead of EditText in the xml. :)

Comment: Yes of course, though I cannot rate it yet, don't have 15 reputation.

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText **...**  at com.sandtdevelopment.getrich.ContributeActivity.cont_sendEmail(ContributeActivity.java:18)

You're trying to cast a `TextView` to an `Editview` on line 18